# Мониторинг сервиса

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, мониторинг, fastapi

Задача снимать метрики из сервиса. Каким образом это делается обычно?

Мы захотели использовать прометея и столкнулись с неожиданной проблемой. У нас flask/fastapi вместе со стандартной связкой uvicorn (ELB) (можно nginx). При этом, возникает трудность в том, что каждый из работающих воркеров за ELB имеет свои метрики. Тогда оказывается, что прометеус будет запрашивать эти метрики и получать разные ответы от разных воркеров. Как решаете эту проблему?

## Более формально

Балансер — [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/). Workers — [fastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/), каждый из которых выставляет наружу эндпоинт прометеуса (на картинке **P**).

**Проблема**. Каждый воркер выставляет свой эндпоинт. Тогда в прометее оказывается много графиков по метрикам. Как решается такая проблема в среднем?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> решали эту проблему сбором метрик в statsd а оттуда в прометей

> https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#multiprocess-mode-gunicorn

> https://github.com/denisgolius/flussonic-exporter

> https://flussonic.ru/doc/api/http-api-k-flussonic-media-server/